# Redirecting stderr in C

Tags: c, stderr

I'm writing a simple shell in C and encountered a minor problem.
I have the following function:

```
int execStdErr(char** parsedArguments, int numberOfArgs) {
  fflush(stderr);
  int fd;
  int parsedCommandLength = 0;
  char** parsedCommand = parseLine(parsedArguments[0], &parsedCommandLength);
  parsedArguments[numberOfArgs - 1] = deleteSpaces(parsedArguments[numberOfArgs - 1]);
  if (fork() == 0) {
    if (fd = open(parsedArguments[numberOfArgs - 1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT |O_TRUNC,  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) < 0) {
      perror("lsh");
      return 1;
    }
    if (dup2(fd, 2) < 0) {
     perror("lsh") ;
     return 1;
    }
    close(fd);
    execvp(parsedCommand[0], parsedCommand);
    exit(0);
  }
  close(fd);
  wait(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

parsedArguments are arguments splitted by `2>`, then I take the last one as it is name of my file, and I process the previous one by splitting them on spaces (and they are in `parsedCommand`). For some reason the `stderr` prints on screen, it creates a file if it didn't exist but it is always empty. I don't know what might be the problem here.

Comment: There's clearly a cut-n-paste error on your `if( fd = open ...`, and I suspect you're just misgrouping, as I would expect to see `if( ( fd = open ...) < 0)`.   Hard to be sure since that line is truncated by the apparent cut and paste error.

Comment: Right, I fixed it.

Comment: You definitely need to add parens.  If open succeeds, then it is not < 0, so fd gets assigned 0, not the value returned by open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common error:

```
if (fd = open(...) < 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
 if (fd = (open(...) < 0))
```

which is not what you want.  You need:

```
 if ( (fd = open(...)) < 0)
```

When `open` succeeds, `open(...) < 0` evaluates to false and `fd = open(...) < 0` assigns `0` to `fd`.  The value returned by `open`, however, is lost.